# ORACLE + PHP oci_execute() got freeze and not return anything

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I am trying to execute oracle SQL statement using below code.

```
$ofe_id = '123';    
$stmt = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, "DECLARE
l_retval     VARCHAR2(255);
l_message    VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
l_retval := offerte.fill_temp_fields(:ofe_id,l_message);
END;") or die("Cannot parse query");

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':ofe_id', $ofe_id);
//        $err = oci_error($stmt); //It return 'false';
$respose = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

I am using PHP 5.6 with Ubuntu 14.0x. 
When I tried to execute above statement. It freeze and return nothing.

When I tried to debug the code I found that It executes till oci_execute() , After that it will not execute for the next code. I was waiting till 30 minutes but seems that it not returned any response.

Answer (score 2):

You might have another Oracle session open and have some locks around your table.

Sorry, I'm not an expert but I used to have similar problems when testing Oracle capabilities at the same time from PHP-Apache and from PHP-CLI with several different SQL+ prompts open (e.g. SYSDBA, schema owner and non-privileged user). After committing the "freezing oci_execute" error disappeared.

You should specify the corrent type and size for your variable, however:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':ofe_id', $ofe_id, -1, SQLT_INT);
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Both PHP and Oracle do silent type conversion between numbers and numeric strings, but sometimes the tailing characters can be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just use OCI_DEFAULT prior to PHP 5.3.2, use OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT instead... Can't say if this will solve all your problems because I can't reproduce this error right now, but I'm almost sure that this can help.

Comment: Thanks but it still remain same.